# Animation dont execute

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, mkmapview

I want to change size of mapView on button action, so I have got two functions to do this.

```
func makeFullScreenMap() {
    println(self.heightConstraint.constant)
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.frame.height
    println(self.heightConstraint.constant)
    self.mapView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

}

func makeHideScreenMap() {

    self.heightConstraint.constant = 0
    self.mapView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

else, I have action where I am tracking button state and choosing what exact method I need to use.

```
  @IBAction func fullScreen(sender: AnyObject) {

        println(changeMapButton.state.rawValue)

        if changeMapButton.state == UIControlState.Highlighted {
            makeFullScreenMap()
            changeMapButton.selected = true

        } else {
            changeMapButton.highlighted = true
            makeHideScreenMap()
        }

    }
```

Problem is - when it is animating down it makes it with animation and slowly making mapView bigger. When I am using method makeHideScreenMap() it is changing in moment, and then scrollling the map view animated. I need it to do slowly animated like changing frame. Any advices?

Comment: Can you try to replace self.mapView with self.view.layoutIfNeeded() inside animation block?

Comment: @Greg if you will post answer - I will make it rated, cause it solved my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `self.mapView.layoutIfNeeded()` with `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside animation block because the constraints you layout are child of view not mapView.

Answer (score 0):

Try animating using this. Please manage coordinates according to your need.

```
let trans = CGAffineTransformScale(mapView.transform, 1.00, 1.00)
UIView .animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

        self. mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self. mapView.transform, 100.0, 100.0)

        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
    })
```

Comment: I need to change some constraints, so your code wont help me in my need

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't work with the auto layout. You need to adjust the constraint and update.